# Emacs: indentation takes 4 spaces instead of 2

Tags: indentation

When I write code in Emacs and press <kbd>Return</kbd>, the indentation is automatically set to 4 spaces even if I set it yo 2:

```
(setq tab-width 2) ; or any other preferred value
    (defvaralias 'c-basic-offset 'tab-width)
    (defvaralias 'cperl-indent-level 'tab-width)
```

How to fix this?

Here is my full **.emacs** configuration (half of which is taken from [here](http://codewinds.com/blog/2015-04-02-emacs-flycheck-eslint-jsx.html)):

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(ansi-color-faces-vector
   [default default default italic underline success warning error])
 '(ansi-color-names-vector
   ["black" "red3" "ForestGreen" "yellow3" "blue" "magenta3" "DeepSkyBlue" "gray50"])
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (wheatgrass)))
 '(custom-safe-themes
   (quote
    ("87a431903d22fa1cbb2becd88572e7d985e28c2253935448d0d754c13e85a980" "ae3a3bed17b28585ce84266893fa3a4ef0d7d721451c887df5ef3e24a9efef8c" "08a89acffece58825e75479333109e01438650d27661b29212e6560070b156cf" default)))
 '(fci-rule-color "dark green")
 '(highlight-symbol-colors
   (quote
    ("#EFFF00" "#73CD4F" "#83DDFF" "MediumPurple1" "#66CDAA" "DarkOrange" "HotPink1" "#809FFF" "#ADFF2F")))
 '(hl-paren-background-colors
   (quote
    ("#00FF99" "#CCFF99" "#FFCC99" "#FF9999" "#FF99CC" "#CC99FF" "#9999FF" "#99CCFF" "#99FFCC" "#7FFF00")))
 '(hl-paren-colors (quote ("#326B6B")))
 '(org-src-block-faces (quote (("emacs-lisp" (:background "#F0FFF0")))))
 '(package-selected-packages
   (quote
    (exec-path-from-shell js2-mode flycheck heroku organic-green-theme vue-mode vue-html-mode green-screen-theme green-is-the-new-black-theme green-phosphor-theme web-mode php-mode json-mode))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )


;; load emacs 24's package system. Add MELPA repository.
(when (>= emacs-major-version 24)
  (require 'package)
  (add-to-list
   'package-archives
   ;; '("melpa" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/") ; many packages won't show if using stable
   '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")
   t))


(setq column-number-mode t)



;; use web-mode for .jsx files
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.jsx$" . web-mode))



(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("MELPA Stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
(package-refresh-contents)

(package-install 'flycheck)

(global-flycheck-mode)




;; turn on flychecking globally
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)

;; disable jshint since we prefer eslint checking
(setq-default flycheck-disabled-checkers
  (append flycheck-disabled-checkers
    '(javascript-jshint)))

;; use eslint with web-mode for jsx files
(flycheck-add-mode 'javascript-eslint 'web-mode)

;; customize flycheck temp file prefix
(setq-default flycheck-temp-prefix ".flycheck")

;; disable json-jsonlist checking for json files
(setq-default flycheck-disabled-checkers
  (append flycheck-disabled-checkers
    '(json-jsonlist)))

;; https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell
;; only need exec-path-from-shell on OSX
;; this hopefully sets up path and other vars better
(when (memq window-system '(mac ns))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))

;; use local eslint from node_modules before global
;; http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21205/flycheck-with-file-relative-eslint-executable
(defun my/use-eslint-from-node-modules ()
  (let* ((root (locate-dominating-file
                (or (buffer-file-name) default-directory)
                "node_modules"))
         (eslint (and root
                      (expand-file-name "node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js"
                                        root))))
    (when (and eslint (file-executable-p eslint))
      (setq-local flycheck-javascript-eslint-executable eslint))))
(add-hook 'flycheck-mode-hook #'my/use-eslint-from-node-modules)

;; adjust indents for web-mode to 2 spaces
(defun my-web-mode-hook ()
  "Hooks for Web mode. Adjust indents"
  ;;; http://web-mode.org/
  (setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2)
  (setq web-mode-css-indent-offset 2)
  (setq web-mode-code-indent-offset 2))
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook  'my-web-mode-hook)

;; for better jsx syntax-highlighting in web-mode
;; - courtesy of Patrick @halbtuerke
(defadvice web-mode-highlight-part (around tweak-jsx activate)
  (if (equal web-mode-content-type "jsx")
    (let ((web-mode-enable-part-face nil))
      ad-do-it)
    ad-do-it))

(setq tab-width 2) ; or any other preferred value
    (defvaralias 'c-basic-offset 'tab-width)
    (defvaralias 'cperl-indent-level 'tab-width)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/31104/105) to a similar question. That answer doesn't answer that question, because it is about Ruby mode not respecting such code. But it likely does answer your similar question.

This is that answer, adjusted for your preference of 2 spaces:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 2)
(setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)
```

Keep in mind that some modes might override (not respect) such settings. If you find that you see the problem in a specific mode, then modify your question to be about that -- specify the problematic mode(s). That's the case for the question with the answer I referred to (Ruby mode is problematic).

---

In general, please don't just dump your init file here. If you feel something from it is relevant then you can show just that part. If you have no idea whether something from it is relevant, you can try bisecting to find out. If you can't find out whether anything in it is relevant, please don't bother posting any of it.